# How do I use node modules in a react application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have built the basic interface of an application that will help me analyze charts better. I want to place orders and view my positions on this app directly through the help of alpaca API. How do I achieve this functionality since I cannot import node modules in the jsx files?

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. You certainly can import from packages installed in `node_modules` in jsx files. You are already doing it with `import React from 'react'`.

Comment: With that said, what exact difficulty have you encountered? Have you tried to make a request to the Alpaca API?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry for being vague, what I meant was I cannot import modules to my react application if they do not use ES6 import export syntax. The alpaca API uses commonjs require() syntax which is not supported in the browser. So, I inevitably need to create a backend which can handle the requests

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add those details along with a code example that duplicates the problem you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed alpaca library for js using:
`npm install --save @alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api`.
You can import this package in react.js application using ES Modules:
`import "Alpaca" from "@alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api"`

Next you should initialize API using your configuration options, which you've got after registration in API website

```
const alpaca = new Alpaca({
  keyId: 'YourKeyId',
  secretKey: 'YourSecretKey',
  paper: true,
})
```

Below I attached a link to the documentation of alpaca-trade-api - js library, you can read how to make a connection using Alpaca API. If everything will be ok, you will should be able to send API request.

[Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api)

Comment: It's not an ES module, it can only be used using require() from node